# Initialize matrix with all the combinations from an array of objects in C++

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie programmer trying to solve the following problem: I need to initialize a matrix with all the combinations from a array of objects so I can extract the values and perform certain calculations afterwards for each set of objects, in this case I used a struct for X, Y coordinates to represent the data. The entire data set consists on 35 coordinates, for now I'm dealing with as few data as possible, an input array of size 4,  meaning 4 (n) combinations of 3 (r) objects. The program seems to work fine until I print the 4x3 matrix and find out I was only able to store the first combination, and after tinkering with the program I got stuck since I didn't code this program entirely. Could someone suggest me a solution so the matrix gets initialized correctly? I'd highly appreciate it.

```
#include <iostream>
#define n 4 //data set size
#define r 3 // combination size
using namespace std;

struct Points{
  double x, y;  
};

void Combination(Points Data [n], Points CombinationMatrix [][r],int start, int currLen, bool check []) {
    // Return if the currLen is more than the required length.
    if(currLen > r)
    return;
    // If currLen is equal to required length then add the sequence.
    else if (currLen == r){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < r; j++){
                if (check[i] == true){
                    CombinationMatrix[i][j] = Data[j]; 
                } 
        }
    }
        return;
    }
    // If start equals to len then return since no further element left.
    if (start == n) 
    {
        return;
    }
    // For every index we have two options.
    // First is, we select it, means put true in check[] and increment currLen and start.
    check[start] = true;
    Combination(Data, CombinationMatrix, start + 1, currLen + 1, check);
    // Second is, we don't select it, means put false in check[] and only start incremented.
    check[start] = false;
    Combination(Data, CombinationMatrix, start + 1, currLen, check);
}

int main()
{
    Points Data [n] = { {1, 1}   , {2, 7}    ,  {3, 6}   , {4, 13}};  //, {5,9}    ,
                    //{6, 7}   , {7, 12}   ,  {8, 14}  , {9, 17}  , {10, 23} ,
                    //{11,28}  , {12, 63}  ,  {13, 45} , {14, 68} , {15, 32} , 
                    //{16,98}  , {17, 115} ,  {18, 116}, {19, 112}, {20, 115}, 
                    //{21, 88} , {22, 86}  ,  {23, 106}, {24, 136}, {25, 158}, 
                    //{26, 198}, {27, 128} ,  {28, 187}, {29, 112}, {30, 149},
                    //{31, 279}, {32, 224} ,  {33, 222}, {34, 260}, {35, 166}};
    Points CombinationMatrix [n][r];

    bool check[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        check[i] = false;
    }

    Combination(Data, CombinationMatrix, 0, 0, check);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < r; j++){
           cout << CombinationMatrix[i][j].x << "," << CombinationMatrix[i][j].y << " ";
        }
    cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the expected output.  It is not clear exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you're looking for combinations, there are ways to do this by using a `bool` array and just shifting the values in this array using `next_permutation` to generate the combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you have a look at `std::prev_permutation`.

If you have a `std::vector<Data> points`, then you can get all permutations via

```
  do {
      // Do something with the current permutation
      for ( int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i ) {
           std::cout << points[i] << ' ';
      }
      std::cout << '\n';
  } while ( std::prev_permutation(points.begin(),points.end()) );
```

Since this gives you `points.size()`! (Factorial) combinations, I would not store it in a matrix unless you have a very good reason to do so.

`std::prev_permutation` uses the `lexicographically smaller`. Thus, you need to overload the `operator <` for `Data`.

```
inline bool operator< (const Data& lhs, const Data& rhs){ 
    /* do actual comparison e.g.*/ 
    return ((lhs.x <rhs.x) && (lhs.y <rhs.y));
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for combinations, not permutations.  You can still use `prev_permutation` in getting the combinations, but it takes more than what your code is showing.

Answer (score 0):

The following generates combinations of your array using `std::prev_permutation`.

Note that this is accomplished by using a `bool` vector that starts with `r` of those bits set to `true`, and on each iteration the bits in the `bool` vector have their positions changed.

The following uses `std::vector<Point>` instead of hard-coded arrays.  This adds flexibility in that you don't have to guess how many combinations will be generated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Points {
    double x, y;
};

std::vector<std::vector<Points>> Combination(std::vector<Points>& Data, int n, int r)
{
    // The returned vector  
    std::vector<std::vector<Points>> retVect;

    // Array of bools
    std::vector<bool> bits(n);

    // Fill the first r positions of the bool array to true
    std::fill(bits.begin(), bits.begin() + r, true);

    // Our temporary 1 dimensional array we use when building a single combination
    std::vector<Points> tempV;
    do 
    {
        tempV.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
        {
            // for each item in the bool array that's true, add that to the vector
            if (bits[i]) 
                tempV.push_back(Data[i]);
        }

        // add this combination to vector of combinations 
        retVect.push_back(tempV);

      // rearrange the bits
    } while (std::prev_permutation(bits.begin(), bits.end()));
    return retVect;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Points> Data = { {1, 1}, {2, 7}, {3, 6}, {4, 13} };  
    auto CombinationMatrix = Combination(Data, 4, 3);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < CombinationMatrix.size(); i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < CombinationMatrix[i].size(); j++) {
           std::cout << "{" << CombinationMatrix[i][j].x << "," << CombinationMatrix[i][j].y << "} ";            }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{1,1} {2,7} {3,6} 
{1,1} {2,7} {4,13} 
{1,1} {3,6} {4,13} 
{2,7} {3,6} {4,13}
```